# Convergence of a sequence with respect to a distance.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

Recall that a sequence $a$ in a set $M$ converges to $L \in M$ with respect to the distance $d$ on M, if for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n \gt n_\epsilon$ we have $d(a(n), L) \lt \epsilon$.

---

> Let $d$ be a distance on $\mathbb{R}^+=(0, \infty)$ given by $\displaystyle d(x,y) = \lvert\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\rvert$.
>
> Which of the sequences 
>   $$
> (n^2 + n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},
> $$ 
>   $$
> (\frac{\sin(k)+k^2}{\root\of{1+3k^4}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
> $$ 
>   $$((-1)^j+2)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$$ converge with respect to $d$ and which are Cauchy sequences with respect to $d$?

I am stuck on how to give a formal proof to show that 1 and 3 diverge. Could someone please point me in the right direction as how to formally state it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two metric spaces $(X_i,d_i),\ i=1,2$ are said isometric iff there exists an onto $u:\ X_1\rightarrow X_2$ s.t.
$$
(\forall x,y\in X_1)(d_2(u(x),u(y))=d_1(x,y))
$$ 
it is straightforward to see that such an isometry transforms ``one-to-one'' convergent and Cauchy sequences.

Here, your isometry, $u(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ sends $(0, \infty)$ ($=]0, \infty[$, I think) to itself and the given distance $d=d_1$ to $d_2(x,y)=|x-y|$ (i.e. the classic one). The question amounts to see which of the sequences 
$$
(\frac{1}{n^2 + n})_{n \geq 1};\ \displaystyle(\frac{\root\of{1+3k^4}}{\sin(k)+k^2})_{k\geq 1};\ (\frac{1}{(-1)^j+2})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}
$$
converge with respect to $d_2$ (the ordinary one) and which are Cauchy sequences in $]0, \infty[$. Now the metric space $X_2=(]0, \infty[,d_2)$ can be embedded in the complete space $X_3=([0, \infty[,d_3);\ d_3(x,y)=|x-y|$ and it is dense in it. So, $X_3$ being complete, the Cauchy sequences of $X_2$ are exactly those who converge in $X_3$.

To summarize, your first sequence is Cauchy (it converges to zero in $X_3$), the second is convergent to $\sqrt{3}$ and the third oscillates between two values and is not Cauchy (and then not convergent).

Comment: $(0, \infty)$ is the open interval between 0 and $\infty$.

Comment: @user372834 So I maintain that the open interval between $0$ and $+\infty$ is NOT classical for $\mathbb{R}_+=[0,+\infty[$

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence converges, then it must converge to some limit $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Now let's take a look at the distance in question 1:
$$\left|{1\over n^2+n}-{1\over L}\right|\to {1\over |L|}\neq 0.$$
Since the distance cannot converge to zero, the sequence diverges.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am stuck on how to give a formal proof to show that 1 and 3 diverge."

Denote your sequence by $\{a_n\}$.

- Can you write down using *definition* of $d$ **what it means** by saying $\{a_n\}$ converges to some $a$ in the metric $d$?
- Can you identify a contradiction there?